# how to solve undefined event for dialogflow cx

Tags: dialogflow-cx

i'm able to catch event.detail.response.responseId and event.detail.response.queryResult.languageCode from Dialogflow Api in javascript (in function  for df-response-received event).

But event.detail.response.queryResult.intent.displayName is undefined.  Same thing for intent.name

What could be the reason why Dialogflow api returns undefined values ?

thanks
Regards

i expected to retrieve the intent name.

Comment: hi all, by the way.

Comment: i got the same result with event.detail.response.queryResult.match.intent.displayName.